# TypeError: Jsonix.Context is not a function

Tags: node.js, jsonix

I successfully got an schema object created by jsonix. Now I want to convert json strings to xml. This is my code:

```
var Jsonix= require('jsonix');
var context= new Jsonix.Context([myschemaobj]);
```

here I get the error that Jsonix.Context is not a function.
What ist wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you generated a mapping file and 'required' it using something like `var PO = require('./mappings/PO').PO;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsonix node.js module exports an object named `Jsonix``. So you have to require Jsonix and your mappings as follows:

```
var Jsonix = require('jsonix').Jsonix;
var PO = require('./PO/Mappings').PO;
```

And then:

```
var context = new Jsonix.Context([ PO ]);
var unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
var result = unmarshaller.unmarshalString('<comment>test</comment>');
test.equal('comment', result.name.localPart);
test.equal('test', result.value);
```

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of Jsonix.

Comment: Thank you lexicore. I followed your advice. I got a new error message:  Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined .... node_modules/jsonix/jsonix.js:44:18  I have to mention that I had created the "myschemaobj" under windows,  and then copied it to my project folder in ubuntu (vb). The reason is I have no java runtime env in my ubuntu virtualbox environment. Is that possibly an error source?

Comment: No, Jsonix runtime has no dependency on Java, it's pur JavaScript. Please provide your source code and the full error stack trace.

Comment: My mistake :) I had forgotten to instantiate the Jsonix-class(new-keyword forgotten: var context=  Jsonix.Context([myschemaobj]);   )